# How to calculate the average of different categories?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

If I have large dataset composed of different categories of age (5, 10, 20, 25, 30, ....). I'd like to calculate the average height for each age. Is there a function that can be used to do so?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that using PivotTable is the best choice here:

1. Select your dataset and click the PivotTable button under Insert:

   [image]
2. Drag and drop each field into the boxes; Age into the Row Labels box and Height into the Values box:

   [image]
3. Then change to averages:

   [image]

---

To add a median, put the formula:

```
=MEDIAN(IF($B$2:$B$100=B2,$A$2:$A$100))
```

in cell C2 and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> and drag the formula down. Change the range as required though. Then either update the range of the pivot table (PivotTable Options, change source) or create a new one. The put it under values and change the summarisation to 'Max' (It doesn't matter whether it's Max or Min since it's the same median for each age:

[image]

Comment: @aelwan I added a way to get the median in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use the subtotals feature. On the 'Data' ribbon, there's a subtotals button. Put the cursor in your table and click the button. The UI is fairly intuitive.

Subtotals is not just about 'totals' in the sense of SUM, but lets you do averages, min, max and other aggregate functions.

Comment: How can I calculate the median for each category?